# How to use cross browser testing in Specflow Playwright C# linking with specflow.actions.json

Tags: c#, cross-browser, specflow, playwright-dotnet

My JSON file is:

```json
specflow.actions.json file

{
  "target": {
    "defaultTimeout": 60,
    "headless": false,
    "traceDir": "traces"
  }
}

My custom json file I am willing to use for targetting different browsers and OS

{
  "BrowserTypes": [
      {
        "BrowserName": "Chrome",
        "OS": [ "Win10_Chrome", "Win11_Chrome", "Mac" ]
      },
      {
        "BrowserName": "Edge",
        "OS": [ "Win10_Chrome" ]
      },
      {
        "BrowserName": "Mobile",
        "OS": [ "IOS_Chrome", "Android_Chrome" ]
      }
    ],
    "DefaultBrowser": [ "Chrome", "Mobile" ],
    "DefaultEnvironment": "Demo"
}
```

I am new to Specflow playwright c# and I want to see how we can achieve Cross bowser testing.
I have gone through the document provided at [git](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Actions/tree/3d0fcac2632473f142597faccf5f5a902c211716/Plugins/SpecFlow.Actions.Playwright/SpecFlow.Actions.Playwright), but I am unable to tweak the configuration at runtime.

I am expecting to control the configuration at runtime so that the test cases run for the defined browsers at run time

Comment: You are linking to the source code. Try this URL: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Actions/tree/main/Plugins/SpecFlow.Actions.Playwright - it is the root page for the plugin, which has a readme file.

Comment: Based on the JSON structure in the link in my previous comment, it doesn't look like you cannot specify configurations for multiple browsers are the same time.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - thanks for the update.

I am willing to use the custom config.json file and structure mentioned instead of creating multiple specflow.actions.Target1.json for each targets.

Is their any way I can use it so that my single test covers all the browsers with capabilities.

Comment: I think you misread my comment. It does not appear like you can use one config file for multiple browser configurations. It looks like you need one config file per browser. You will probably need to run each test once for each browser you wanted supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [runsettings](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-runners#using-the-runsettings-file) file to get a value

Then using that value you can read the json file and get further configuration

That configuration , lets say chrome / windows10 can be passed to browser instance at run time to decide which configuration to run.

Also another idea would be lets say your piepline runs twice a day , based on day / time pass a browser. This way you need not to run all test in all browsers and you can save time and cost